# How to count recurrence of words in JavaScript text

Tags: javascript

So, here's the thing.

I need to read a text and count the recurrence of each individual word.
After that, I need to do some manipulations and remove some values.

I found this code in a similar question:

```js
let text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
let words = text.split(" ");
let obj = {};
let i = 0;
let len = words.length

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (obj[words[i]] === undefined) {
    obj[words[i]] = 1;
  } else {
    obj[words[i]]++;
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

And it works fine, except I can access it as a whole, but not individual values (probably because I'm not well versed in JavaScript).

Then I thought about using a simple approach, making an object with the properties 'word' and 'count' and pushing into an array:

```js
let text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'

let words = text.split(" ");

    let array = [];
    let obj = [];
    let i = 0;
    let len = words.length

    for ( i=0 ; i<words.length ; i++ ){
        obj.word = words[i];
        obj.count = 1;
        array.push(obj);
    }

console.log(array);
```

But somehow I get a [circular object Array] result.

So, I wanted to know what is wrong with either of the codes, or a possible alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you define `object` as an array and then try to add a property. That is part of the problem. The other is you're trying to reuse the same object every time you loop - you are changing the word and count, but it's the same object, which is causing the circular error.

Here's one way to approach it. Do your loop and try to find an existing reference to the word using `findIndex` - if it exists increment the count, otherwise add a new entry.

Also, so we capture that last word in the sentence without the period (or any commas), we can strip those out with `text.replace(/[,.-]/g, '')`. Finally, so we can compare the first word (capitalized) with any matches along the way, we'll convert all comparisons to lowercase.

```js
let text = 'Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum dolor amet sit amet.'
let words = text.replace(/[,.-]/g, '').split(" ");
let array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  let exists = array.findIndex(a => a.word.toLowerCase() === words[i].toLowerCase());
  if (exists > -1) array[exists].count++;
  else array.push({
    word: words[i],
    count: 1
  });
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: It would have been nicer had you gone with linear+linear. Also what if there is a question/exclamation mark among others, your solution fails.

Comment: @EugenSunic - You're right. I didn't want to go down the punctuation rabbit hole, but more validation can be added to the regex. Also, what is linear + linear?

Answer (score -1):

You can acces individual values by calling `obj['Lorem']` for example it's a key value map.